# Touch screen acting weird (P9)

Tags: hardware, touchscreen

I recently got a new touchscreen, which seems to work (since you can see the touches in debug mode), but sometimes it just won't swipe from one page to another! This also happens in an app. What is wrong, I don't get it?

Video: https://puu.sh/xtaow/ed633e8833.mp4

PS: When swiping slower it sometimes works better, but not always.
PPS: When having the phone in my left hand, I can only swipe right and vice versa. When having the phone on my table everything works perfectly.

Phone: Huawei P9 (EVA-L09)
Android: Nougat 7

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should increase your touch sensitivity. Try apps like [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=apps.redpi.touchscreenrepair&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Dandroid%20touchscreen%20sensitivity&pcampaignid=APPU_1_SG2yWcrPBIiUUa_eq5AJ).